# Is it fine to ask user to contact for their work?

Tags: discussion

I'd answered on a question, the OP seems to be unaware of new updated in that technology. Though the previously working app is no longer working for current version. Even after my answer with official sources documentation, OP asked to solve the issue in his code only without adopting new updates, *and believe me that's not possible with his code*.

Though I commented like this,

> This will surely not work with his code, he can adopt new things to solve this issues [that's really easy once he get started on it], or if he want, I can solve all his issues in his app, feel free to contact me.

I'm not sure, this is fine or not? If this is against SO policy, I can delete my comment right away.

FYI, I'm 100% sure that its not possible to solve the issue with his written code, and if he don't want to code for self then (if he wants then) only he can contact me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you come to our site and give us lots of great stuff, we couldn't possible begrudge you the occasional opportunity should one present itself. That said, you have to be careful.

If you've:

- Made your absolute best effort to help the person on the site
- Are certain that it's obvious that the scope of what the user needs is way beyond what we could provide in Q&A format
- Are certain that the user would in fact appreciate such an offer

Then you're welcome to say something like this:

> What you want to do goes way beyond the scope of what we could work out here. I've told you how to get where you want to be, if you still need help at this level we'd need to take it offline. My contact information is in my profile if you care to get in touch.

Then leave it at that. Make sure you have your information in your profile. ***Do this only after answering the question to the best of your ability*** - there's a very fine line between doing your best to help someone within the confines of the site and realizing that they just need *a lot* more help than they planned for, and just dropping your contact information on any question you might be able to answer. Don't do the latter.

I've had to get in touch with folks while answering questions about hypervisors and device drivers because the only way I'd really be able to see what's actually happening is to watch something break for myself. And yeah, I made a few bucks along the way. The point is, I didn't set *out* to do that, I just wanted to answer a question and hopefully get some rep & badges for it, but it ended up that what they actually needed was a consultant.

There's plenty of folks that are happy to say "If you like the kind of answers I give, buy my book" - and the community is fine with that. There's nothing wrong with saying "If you like the kind of answers I give, I'm available to help off-site too!" - ***provided that you're giving us stuff of lasting value***.

Just be careful. Don't be spammy, don't do it often and make sure you've done as much as you can *here* prior to taking it offline.

Oh, and - do remove the comment once a reasonable amount of time (for them to have read it) has passed, it's just noise in the grand scheme of things.