# Is it acceptable to ask other users for their contact information?

Tags: discussion, comments, users

Just stumbled across this (low-quality) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315260/

Despite the question violating just about all rules on the SO network, someone made the effort to answer the question in a comment. OP proceeded to ask this person for his contact information:

> Ohhhh nice Akhilrajtr... thax , thax , thax, that solved... )) Pls give me your fb

Is this kind of behavior acceptable? To be it feels like he finally found someone who is 'willing' to answer his low-quality questions and wants to use him as a personal mentor or something.

I have flagged the comment as rude/offensive. Was this the correct choice?

---

@Duplicate vote: [Is it fine to ask user to contact for their work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280603/is-it-fine-to-ask-user-to-contact-for-their-work) is asking if **the person answering** can provide his contact information. This would be done via "check my profile and send me an email if you want". I am asking if the person **asking a question** can ask a person answering, who does not share his email publicly, for this information.

Comment: Meh, as you say, the entire question needs nuking

Comment: @Pekka웃 I would still like to know about this behavior in general.

Comment: Yeah. If I were a mod I would probably respond to a flag like that and delete with prejudice, but I don't know what the consensus is.

Comment: I don't think that comment is rude or offensive. Personally I'd decline a request like that, or ignore it.

Comment: @rene My question was intended the other way around - from person posting the question to person posting an answer.

Comment: Yeah, really different situation...

Comment: Lets just put it like this: if this becomes a thing, I'm going to fight for the creation of catfish.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are free to ask anything in relation to the context of the question in comments.

That includes efforts to get hold of the private contact information of users if they see fit.

It is up to the user addressed if they respond to such requests. As soon as this gets into a back- and forth exchange of comments to convince the user to hand over private info feel free to flag such comments as `too chatty`.

Taking a discussion off-line and continue to resolve the question in private is not in the spirit of the Stack Exchange sites. It would be more beneficial to all of us if the posts and the discussion to get unclear stuff resolved would  remain in public and on-site, if not in comments then maybe in a chat-room.

Users that are willing to share contact information can do so in their user profile. A simple comment to point that out should be enough. For those that decided to not share that kind of information, their privacy should be respected and guarded by the same rules Stack Exchange has in their [privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy).

Asking on a random post for a user to share contact details should be considered impolite if not rude.

Comment: Agreed. I've found that most people don't like to be asked for their personal contact information in public posts on this site, so I remove any comments that I see which ask for this. Additionally, we've had some disturbing problems with certain users who ask for personal information of anyone with a female name or avatar in an apparent attempt to hit on them. We take stronger actions when we see that.