# Unrequested (support request, not spam) email offsite

Tags: discussion

My question, or point of discussion, is somewhat related, but different from:

- [Is it acceptable to ask other users for their contact information?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298883/is-it-acceptable-to-ask-other-users-for-their-contact-information)
- [Should we be able to send private messages to other users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261885/should-we-be-able-to-send-private-messages-to-other-users/261887#261887)
- [What do I do about receiving an offensive email from another user on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261941/what-do-i-do-about-receiving-an-offensive-email-from-another-user-on-stack-overf)
- [Recruiter claims to have gotten my email address from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318621/recruiter-claims-to-have-gotten-my-email-address-from-stack-overflow)

---

Yesterday I added a comment to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465386/naming-multiple-pdfs-using-itext-filestream, I asked for a bit of clarification.

When I visit that question now, I get

> Page Not Found
>
> This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

So only you 10k+ users will be able to view it. But the question itself doesn't really matter.

This morning I found an email in my work mailbox, from someone I don't know, with a Yahoo address. I'm a QA Engineer, my only external email contacts are a couple of mailing lists, and notifications from services I use. So I am always surprised when I get an external "cold email".

This is the content of the email I got:

> Hello Amedee,     I started a port regarding the naming of my pdfs
>   using the itext filestream, however I seem to have deleted it... (i've
>   also added additional code)regardless, the idea is that I will be
>   merging pdf's in the source directory based on the file prefix.So I
>   could have 27 files, but there might only be 5 prefixes... Once I
>   merge the 1st set of prefixes, I want to move on to the next prefix.I
>   currently can't name my newly created pdf as I set the name 1st...so
>   that's issue number 1. Next I can't open the 2nd PDF to do any merging
>   because in my below code, I don't open another document....So that
>   must be in the wrong place also. (Side bar...the below code does find
>   the 1st set of prefixes and merges them correctly...)Thanks for any
>   thoughts.
>
> ```
> string outputpathPDF = "C:/here/";
>         var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(scrDir);
>         string prevFileName = null;
>         int i = 1;
>         using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(outputpathPDF + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))// <-- I'm pretty sure this is wrong...
>         { 
>             Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
>             PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(pdfDoc, stream); 
>             pdfDoc.Open();
>
>             foreach (string file in files)
>                 {
>                  string filename = Left(Path.GetFileName(file), 9);
>                 {
>                         if (prevFileName == null || filename == prevFileName)
>                         {
>                             pdf.AddDocument(new PdfReader(file));
>                             i++;
>                             prevFileName = filename;
>                          }
>                         else
>                          {  //added the else to close the open doc once we have merged all the files with the same file prefix.
>                             pdfDoc.Close();
>                             prevFileName = null;
>                          }
>
>                     }                    }
>             if (pdfDoc != null)
>                 pdfDoc.Close();
>                 prevFileName = null;
>             Console.WriteLine("Done!");
>         }
> ```

As you can see from the content from the mail: it's not spam, it's not abusive, and the content of this email would haven been perfectly appropriate as either a comment or an edit of the original question. He/she doesn't mention StackOverflow at all but it was clear for me from the content.

**EDIT: Can the original question be restored by a SO moderator?** Because from the email of the user I get the impression that it was not intentional, because they write: *'however I seem to have deleted it'*.

Comment: What feedback are you expecting? *"there is little that SO can do about it"* - nothing, actually; the only way to avoid it is for you change your account to be anonymous. *"how do people deal with tech support emails if they aren't doing tech support?"* - that's up to you, forward them, reply to them or ignore them as you see fit. If this is a professional matter, ask inside your company if there's a guideline you should follow.

Comment: Well, the problem is that "your emailId isn't hard to find" and "people need answers to questions that might not be too good (and might have actually been closed on SO)" and they lose nothing from mailing you. *They know who you are, you don't know them :P*.  Although people might have found you based on your SO account, I am not sure if we can do anything to prevent people from mailing you (I removed links to my linkedIn once I got elected because I started getting mails from anonymous users)

Comment: I mostly needed to vent some frustration and since votes on meta questions don't influence reputation... :)

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse: Hm, your comment basically calls for off-topic flagging: This question does not appear to seek input and discussion...

Comment: @honk on second thought, you are absolutely right, and I edited the question again.

Comment: FYI I voted to close my own question and accepted @ChrisF's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your edit:

The OP deleted their own question. I see little merit in reversing that decision. If they still need help they can undelete themselves or post a new (better) question.